# Dashes in JSON schema gives error

Tags: json, meteor

I have an external JSON file that I need to parse, but it gives errors on any field that contains dashes, e.g.

```js
eventdate: item["event-metadata"].event-date-time
```

I have no control over this external feed. 
I tried .["event-date-time"] and ."event-date-time", and .'event-date-time' but these resulted in "unexpected token"

How do I reference these items?

BTW, this is in Meteor.js on a server side.

Comment: did you try `["event-date-time"]` without a dot before?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use dot notation when dashes and other unsupported characters are present. Using dashes in a variable name is invalid for dot notation, so you must index into the object using bracket notation with the string acting as the key and wrapped in quotes:

```
item["event-metadata"]["event-date-time"]
```